# Duplication removal with group by or distinct

Tags: mysql, sql, join, unique

Here I have a query scenario, explained the scope in inline comments:

```
select 
    -- selecting both entity ids
    entity_a.id as entity_a_id, 
    entity_b.id as entity_b_id,
    concat(entity_a.id, entity_b.id) as `key`

from `entity_b` 

-- Following are few one to many relations to match entity a with b
inner join `entity_b_function` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_function`.`entity_b_id` 
inner join `entity_b_category` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_category`.`entity_b_id` 
inner join `entity_b_scope` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_scope`.`entity_b_id` 

inner join `entity_a` on 
    `entity_a`.`category_id` = `entity_b_category`.`category_id` and 
    `entity_a`.`scope_id` = `entity_b_scope`.`scope_id` 
inner join `entity_a_function` on 
    `entity_b_function`.`function_id` = `entity_a_function`.`function_id` 


-- pivot of entity a and b
-- making sure matching entities are finally related in pivot
left join `entity_a_b_pivot` on 
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`entity_a_id` = `entity_a`.`id` and 
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`entity_b_id` = `entity_b`.`id` 

where 
    -- we need only matching entities which are not yet related in pivot
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`id` is null and 
    -- when both entities are active in the system
    `entity_b`.`status` = 1 and 
    `entity_a`.`status` = 1 
LIMIT 5000;
```

Currently resulted as below:
(pointed items are duplication due to joins of one to many relations)

```
entity_a_id,    entity_b_id     key
    1               1           11
>   1               1           11
    1               2           12
    2               1           21
    2               2           22
>   2               2           22
```

Here, if either I use `GROUP BY key` or `DISTINCT(key)` to eliminate the duplicates, the query processing stuck forever with 100% CPU usage but without these it is just a blink to return 5K records but with 90% duplicates.

How to optimize the query for distinct results?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  There is probably a simpler way to do what you want.

Comment: Please post EXPLAIN results for both cases.

Comment: Is the overlap using `concat(entity_a.id, entity_b.id) as key` intentional btw? If `entity_a.id` is 1 and `entity_b.id` is 12, it will have the same key as with `entity_a.id` being 11 and `entity_b.id` being 2.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are joining the entities along different dimensions, resulting in Cartesian products and an inordinate number of rows -- with duplicates.  You need to simplify the query to remove these duplicates, not rather than using `distinct` or `group by` on a malformed result set.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I think group by clause is irritated with this scenario. I tried as you suggested. The second thing is entity_a.id and entity_b.id are not unique in its own.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson That was an example but can addressed with `concat(entity_a.id, '-' ,entity_b.id)`

Comment: @ShuaibNawaz If the query is just an example, I'm not sure optimizing it will reflect as the same speedup on the actual query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson it is not that much exemplary only relabeled for table and field names. However DISTINCT in the beginning makes it perfect but makes 90 times slower.

Answer (score 1):

How about just add `DISTINCT` at beginning of select list?

```
select 
    -- selecting both entity ids
    distinct
    entity_a.id as entity_a_id, 
    entity_b.id as entity_b_id,
    concat(entity_a.id, entity_b.id) as `key`

from `entity_b` 

-- Following are few one to many relations to match entity a with b
inner join `entity_b_function` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_function`.`entity_b_id` 
inner join `entity_b_category` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_category`.`entity_b_id` 
inner join `entity_b_scope` on 
    `entity_b`.`id` = `entity_b_scope`.`entity_b_id` 

inner join `entity_a` on 
    `entity_a`.`category_id` = `entity_b_category`.`category_id` and 
    `entity_a`.`scope_id` = `entity_b_scope`.`scope_id` 
inner join `entity_a_function` on 
    `entity_b_function`.`function_id` = `entity_a_function`.`function_id` 


-- pivot of entity a and b
-- making sure matching entities are finally related in pivot
left join `entity_a_b_pivot` on 
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`entity_a_id` = `entity_a`.`id` and 
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`entity_b_id` = `entity_b`.`id` 

where 
    -- we need only matching entities which are not yet related in pivot
    `entity_a_b_pivot`.`id` is null and 
    -- when both entities are active in the system
    `entity_b`.`status` = 1 and 
    `entity_a`.`status` = 1 
LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: DISTINCT in the start really worked well but query execution time is 44s in comparison to 0.5s without it. :)

Comment: This time is on `sort` operation. `DISTINCT` will do a sort.